# ¿Cómo obtener los datos de un formulario generado dinamicamente en VUE?

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js, template

**Hola, buen día Comunidad.**

Tengo un componente padre que incluye un componente hijo, en el cual renderizo dinámicamente un formulario con distintos controles a partir de un objeto JSON (obtenido mediante una petición Get de Axios).

Mi objetivo es leer/recorrer todos los valores de los campos del formulario que se encuentra en el componente hijo desde el componente padre. ¿Cómo lo haría con Vue JS?

Les dejo a continuación parte del código, si alguien tiene propuestas de mejoras serán bien recibidas. Por ejemplo estructurar mejor el código para que esté más organizado y limpio o utilizar mejores practicas de programación con Vue. Gracias.

**Componente Padre**

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>{{msg}}</h1>
    <b-container>
      <b-card>
        <b-card-title>Formulario Dinámico</b-card-title>
        <b-card-body>
           <FormControls :fields="fields"></FormControls>
        </b-card-body>
        <b-card-footer>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="send">Enviar</button>
        </b-card-footer>
      </b-card>
    </b-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import FormControls from "./FormControls.vue";
import ComponentTest from "./ComponentTest.vue";
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    FormControls,
    ComponentTest
  },
  created() { 
    axios.get('./src/form.json').then(response => this.fields = response.data); 
  },
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Bienvenido',
      fields: [] // Array que almacenará el json proveniente de la petición get
    }
  },
  methods: {
    send: () => {
      alert('Enviar Formulario');
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

**Objeto JSON**

```js
[
    {
      "name": "fechaRegistro",
      "label": "Fecha de Registro",
      "type": "date",
      "placeholder": "Ingresa Fecha"
    },
    {
      "name": "nombreDeUsuario",
      "label": "Nombre de Usuario",
      "type": "text",
      "placeholder": "Ingresa Usuario"
    },
    {
      "name": "passwordUsuario",
      "label": "Password",
      "type": "password",
      "placeholder": "Contraseña"
    },
    {
      "name": "adjuntarArchivo",
      "label": "Adjuntar",
      "type": "file"
    },
    {
      "name": "roles",
      "label": "Roles",
      "type": "select",
      "sortedByKey": false,
      "options": [{
          "name": "admin",
          "label": "Administrador"
        },
        {
          "name": "user",
          "label": "Usuario"
        },
        {
          "name": "guest",
          "label": "Invitado"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "description",
      "label": "Descripción",
      "type": "textarea"
    },
    {
      "name": "multiSelect",
      "label": "Selección Multiple",
      "type": "multiselect",
      "options": [{
          "name": "op1",
          "label": "Opcion1"
        },
        {
          "name": "op2",
          "label": "Opcion2"
        },
        {
          "name": "op3",
          "label": "Opcion3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

**Componente Hijo**

```html
<template>
  <div>
  <form>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="field in fields" :key="field">
        <label :for="field.name">{{field.label}}</label>

        <input v-if="isInput(field.type)" 
        :id="field.name" :type="field.type" :placeholder="field.placeholder" >

        <select v-else-if="field.type === 'select'" :name="field.name">
          <option v-for="opt in field.options" :key="opt" :value="opt.name">
          {{opt.label}}
          </option>
        </select>

        <textarea v-else-if="field.type === 'textarea'" :id="field.name" />
        
        <div v-else-if="field.type === 'multiselect'" class="multi-select">
          <multiselect v-model="values" tag-placeholder="Agregar etiqueta" :placeholder="field.placeholder" label="label" track-by="name" :options="field.options" :multiple="true" :taggable="true" @tag="agregarEtiqueta"></multiselect>
        </div>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['fields'],
  name: 'FormControls',
  data () {
    return {
      titulo: 'Formulario Dinámico',
      // Aqui va lo del MultiSelect
      values: [],
      options: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    isInput(type) {
      return ['text', 'password', 'checkbox', 'file', 'date'].includes(type);
    },
    // metodo multiselect
    agregarEtiqueta (newTag) {
      const tag = {
        name: newTag,
        label: newTag.substring(0, 2) + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000))
      }
      this.options.push(tag)
      this.value.push(tag)
    },
    devolverControl(){

    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se podría hacer de varias maneras...

Se me ocurre que si en el componente hijo creas un objeto donde guardar los valores de los inputs, por ejemplo `values`

```
data: function () {
  return {
    values: {},
  }
},
```

Y desde los inputs vas actualizando ese objeto:

```
<input v-model="values[field.name]" />
```

Cada vez que se modifica un input:

```
<input @input="onInput" />
```

Puedes emitir un evento al componente padre con el objeto donde guardas los valores de todos los inputs:

```
methods: {
  onInput(value) {
    this.$emit('change', this.values);
  },
},
```

Y en el componente padre escuchas ese evento:

```
<form-controls @change="onFieldsChange"></form-controls>
```

Y haces algo con eso:

```
methods: {
  onFieldsChange(value) {
    console.log(value);
  },
},
```

Te dejo un snippet funcional para que le des a *ejecutar* y lo pruebes:

```js
Vue.component('form-controls', {
    props: ['fields'],
    data() {
        return {
            values: this.fields.reduce((acc,curr)=> (acc[curr.name]='',acc),{}),
        }
    },
    methods: {
        isInput(type) {
            return ['text', 'password', 'checkbox', 'file', 'date'].includes(type);
        },
        onInput() {
            this.$emit('change', this.values);
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        this.onInput();
    },
    template: '<div><hr><h3>Hijo</h3><ul><li v-for="(field, index) in fields" :key="index"><input v-if="isInput(field.type)" :type="field.type" v-model="values[field.name]" @input="onInput" /><br>{{field.name}}: {{values[field.name]}}</li></ul><hr></div>'
});

new Vue({
    el: '#components-demo',
    data: {
        fieldsValues: {},
        fields: [
            {
                "name": "fechaRegistro",
                "label": "Fecha de Registro",
                "type": "date",
                "placeholder": "Ingresa Fecha"
            },
            {
                "name": "nombreDeUsuario",
                "label": "Nombre de Usuario",
                "type": "text",
                "placeholder": "Ingresa Usuario"
            },
            {
                "name": "passwordUsuario",
                "label": "Password",
                "type": "password",
                "placeholder": "Contraseña"
            },
            {
                "name": "adjuntarArchivo",
                "label": "Adjuntar",
                "type": "file"
            },
        ],
    },
    methods: {
        onFieldsChange(value) {
            this.fieldsValues = value;
        },
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="components-demo">
  <hr>
  <h3>Padre</h3>
  <pre>{{fieldsValues}}</pre>
  <hr>
  <form-controls :fields="fields" @change="onFieldsChange"></form-controls>
</div>
```

Bien, con eso tienes para empezar. Luego te toca la parte de los select y demás.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Mencionas que se puede hacer de varias formas, ¿hay alguna manera de hacerlo sin utilizar $emit?

Comment: Y otra duda, suponiendo que construyo un tercer componente en el cual mando a renderizar los inputs, es decir un componente hijo del hijo (nivel 3), ¿podría recuperar sus datos desde el padre (nivel 1)? ¿O primero tengo que devolverlos al nivel 2, y este lo pasaría al nivel 1?

Comment: @HugoMixerBS Sin emit: Otra forma sería poniendole un [`ref`](https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Acceso-a-instancias-de-componentes-y-elementos-hijos) al componente hijo, o también puedes usar [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/) si necesitas mantener el estado de un formulario complejo.

Comment: A la duda del hijo nivel 3: Sí, el evento se emite del hijo al padre. O sea, del componente 3 emitir el evento y escucharlo en nivel 2, del nivel 2 emitirlo y escucharlo en el nivel 1.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo probé con ref, sin embargo de esa forma, la lógica se me amontona en el padre tratando de controlar los datos y métodos de todos sus hijos. Yo creo voy a optar por vuex, ya que pienso que podría funcionar como una interfaz "independiente" entre el padre y los distintos hijos (los diversos componentes: tabs, multi-select, input, etc). Lo único es que nunca lo he usado y no tengo mucha idea de como llevarlo a cabo.