# ¿Cómo obtener todos los datos de un formulario que está en un componente hijo desde un Componente Padre? Vue JS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, formularios, webpack

Tengo un **Componente Hijo** que renderiza dinámicamente controles de formulario a partir de un **esquema JSON** proporcionado por un **Componente Padre**.

**Quiero recuperar los datos del formulario al dar clic en un botón desde el componente padre** (los cuales desconoce porque el componente hijo los crea dinámicamente) **¿Cómo podría realizar eso de la mejor manera?** ¿Es necesario que utilice $emit en el componente hijo? ¿Si agrego un componente intermedio, es posible saltarselo o tengo que enviar de un componente a otro respetando su jerarquia?

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>{{msg}}</h1>
    <b-container>
      <b-card>
        <b-card-title>Formulario Dinámico</b-card-title>
        <b-card-body>
           <FormControls :fields="fields"></FormControls>
        </b-card-body>
        <b-card-footer>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="send">Enviar</button>
        </b-card-footer>
      </b-card>
    </b-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import FormControls from "./FormControls.vue";
import ComponentTest from "./ComponentTest.vue";
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    FormControls,
    ComponentTest
  },
  created() { 
    axios.get('./src/form.json').then(response => this.fields = response.data); 
  },
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Bienvenido',
      fields: [] // Array que almacenará el json proveniente de la petición get
    }
  },
  methods: {
    send: () => {
      alert('Enviar Formulario');
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

**Componente hijo**

```js
<template>
  <div>
  <form>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="field in fields" :key="field">
        <label :for="field.name">{{field.label}}</label>

        <input v-if="isInput(field.type)" 
        :id="field.name" :type="field.type" :placeholder="field.placeholder" >

        <select v-else-if="field.type === 'select'" :name="field.name">
          <option v-for="opt in field.options" :key="opt" :value="opt.name">
          {{opt.label}}
          </option>
        </select>

        <textarea v-else-if="field.type === 'textarea'" :id="field.name" />
        
        <div v-else-if="field.type === 'multiselect'" class="multi-select">
          <multiselect v-model="values" tag-placeholder="Agregar etiqueta" :placeholder="field.placeholder" label="label" track-by="name" :options="field.options" :multiple="true" :taggable="true" @tag="agregarEtiqueta"></multiselect>
        </div>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['fields'],
  name: 'FormControls',
  data () {
    return {
      titulo: 'Formulario Dinámico',
      // Aqui va lo del MultiSelect
      values: [],
      options: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    isInput(type) {
      return ['text', 'password', 'checkbox', 'file', 'date'].includes(type);
    },
    // metodo multiselect
    agregarEtiqueta (newTag) {
      const tag = {
        name: newTag,
        label: newTag.substring(0, 2) + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000))
      }
      this.options.push(tag)
      this.value.push(tag)
    },
    devolverControl(){

    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Esquema JSON**

```js
[
    {
      "name": "fechaRegistro",
      "label": "Fecha de Registro",
      "type": "date",
      "placeholder": "Ingresa Fecha"
    },
    {
      "name": "nombreDeUsuario",
      "label": "Nombre de Usuario",
      "type": "text",
      "placeholder": "Ingresa Usuario"
    },
    {
      "name": "passwordUsuario",
      "label": "Password",
      "type": "password",
      "placeholder": "Contraseña"
    },
    {
      "name": "adjuntarArchivo",
      "label": "Adjuntar",
      "type": "file"
    },
    {
      "name": "roles",
      "label": "Roles",
      "type": "select",
      "sortedByKey": false,
      "options": [{
          "name": "admin",
          "label": "Administrador"
        },
        {
          "name": "user",
          "label": "Usuario"
        },
        {
          "name": "guest",
          "label": "Invitado"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "description",
      "label": "Descripción",
      "type": "textarea"
    },
    {
      "name": "multiSelect",
      "label": "Selección Multiple",
      "type": "multiselect",
      "options": [{
          "name": "op1",
          "label": "Opcion1"
        },
        {
          "name": "op2",
          "label": "Opcion2"
        },
        {
          "name": "op3",
          "label": "Opcion3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo obtener los datos de un formulario generado dinamicamente en VUE?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/427886/c%c3%b3mo-obtener-los-datos-de-un-formulario-generado-dinamicamente-en-vue)

Answer (score 0):

1. Puedes utilizar Vuex
2. Puedes cambiar una variable del hijo desde el padre para que el hijo esté observando esa variable (watch) y se ejecuté la acción de recuperar la información
3. Puedes utilizar refs para poder ejecutar un método del hijo directamente desde el padre